# How do I set a hidden menu to visible in a program?

Tags: windows-7, delphi

How do I set a hidden menu to visible in a program?

**background:**

I have an old Delphi application that has a hidden menu with various test tools. But to get it I have to change a flag in the code and recompile the program, and I have no compiler. But the menu is there all the time and has Visible = false.

**Edit1**

Alternatively, if I can run the public methods that the hidden menu items are linked to

Answer (score 0):

If you have the project files you could download and install a free 30 day trial version of RAD Studio XE:

https://downloads.embarcadero.com/free/rad_studio

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the source files, then you're probably out of luck. You may want to try hacking the binary itself. Make a backup of the EXE and then open in Visual Studio or some other binary editor. If you're lucky (and skillful) you may be able to identify where in the binary code the control Visible state is being set, edit the binary code and save the EXE.